# Opencl migration internals

Tags: memory, opencl

I am interested in how OpenCL memory transferring functions operate underneath (migration, reading/writing the buffer, mapping/unmapping). I could not find any open source implementation for OpenCL (for me Intel's one could be fine) and just explanations in the documentation don't give me any idea what is happening, for example, when I call clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects: what calls happen during this migration, what modules are active, how this migration happens, what mechanisms it uses underneath, does it use some cache mechanisms.

Is there a good source to read about it?

I am now  exploring how OpenCL passes data to FPGAs. Xilinx currently uses native OpenCL implementation, present on a machine, plus some extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for low-level information (how a particular implementation implements those calls), probably the only source is the implementation.

There are a few opensource OpenCL on GPU implementations:

Raspberry Pi 3 (beta): https://github.com/doe300/VC4CL

OpenCL on Vulkan (beta): https://github.com/kpet/clvk

Mesa Clover (supports only 1.1): https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/log/?qt=grep&q=clover

AMD ROCm: https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm-OpenCL-Runtime

Intel sources of NEO (their new OpenCL implementation) here: https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime

I'm not aware of Xilinx providing sources for their implementation, so if you want to know what exactly happens on Xilinx, your best chance is probably to ask on Xilinx forums or via some official support.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I looked at Intel and AMD source before, but  didn't manage to track the chain for clEnqueueMigrateMemObjects implementation until the end, it stopped on some enqueue handlers in one case and automatic code generation in another.